# SQL Server Join: Full table vs selected column from table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Just wondering.... what is the difference between

```
select 
    a.field1, b.field1 
from 
    table1 a
inner join 
    table2 b on a.field2 = b.field2
```

and

```
select 
    a.field1, b.field1 
from 
    table1 a 
inner join 
    (select field1, field 
     from table2 ) b on a.field2 = b.field2
```

I've seen this SQL query in one of the legacy systems that I am currently handling. I checked out the execution plan immediately to compare but the results seems the same.

Sorry for being so ignorant. :)

Comment: I'm guessing that in theory - it would reduce the number of columns from table 2 that are returned by the query... eg if table2 has a dozen columns. The second query would only return 2 of them, but the first would return them all

Comment: in the first query table1 is joining with table2 all columns while in the second query newly created temporary  table b has only two columns and joining with table1 which has two or more columns...

Comment: Thank you @TarynEast. I was actually confused by the execution plan since it gives the same result. So basically when joining multiple tables, it would be better to use specific columns only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we use this to optimise performance.

Refer your first query;

```
select a.field1, b.field1  
from table1 a  
inner join table2 b   
on a.field2 = b.field2
```

Actually you have used only 2 columns in table2
(b.field1 to display and b.field2 to join the tables)
So no use of retrieving all the fields in table2.
If table2 consist of highly weighted columns (eg: image, blob) your query response time going to be slow.

Comment: Would you know why the execution plan returns the same result? :-)

Comment: Well the execution plan returns the same results because in the SELECT statement we select same columns in both queries and also use the same condition to join the tables.
Further, if table2 has only field1,field2 then the both queries are identical so the response time should be same (theoretically) .